# Extracting values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I've a pandas dataframe as follows.

```
df = 

     col_1   sum   value_3    value_5   value_7
0    4.0    45.0    NaN         0.9       9.3
1    4.0    NaN     NaN         4.5       NaN
2    49.2   10.8    3.4         NaN       NaN
```

I want to iterate through every row, and from each row, I want the following information to be put in a dictionary. Let `sum_dict` be the dictionary.
For every row, by default, I want the values from `col_1` to be the key and value present in the column `sum` to be the value of dictionary i.e., from first row, the dictionary looks like below

`sum_dict = {4.0 : 45.0}`

In addition to the above if there is a value present in columns `value_3`, `value_5`, `value_7`, I want the column number to be extracted from the column name which will be added as key to the dictionary and the value present in the column will the value to the key in dictionary. Again, for the first row, `sum_dict`looks like follows:

`sum_dict = {4.0 : 45.0, 5.0 : 0.9 , 7.0: 9.3}`

From the second row, the `sum_dict` should look like:

`sum_dict = {4.0: NaN, 5.0 : 4.5}`

Is there a way to do this?

For now I have written the follows:

```
for idx,row in df.iterows():
    sum_dict = {}
    sum_dict[row['col_1']] = row['sum']
```

The above code only the values from `col_1` and `sum` to the dictionary. Is there a way to do the rest as stated above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a similar approach as @Andrej Kesely suggested, you can use `float("".join(char for char in str(key) if char.isnumeric()))` as the dictionary keys, if you don't want to manually type the column indexes:

```py
import pandas as pd

# == Example DataFrame ========================================
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col_1': [4.0, 4.0, 49.2],
        'sum': [45.0, None , 10.8],
        'value_3': [None, None, 3.4],
        'value_5': [0.9, 4.5, None],
        'value_7': [9.3, None, None],
    }
)


# == Solution =================================================
sum_dicts = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    sum_dict = {
        row["col_1"]: row["sum"],
        **{
            float("".join(char for char in str(key) if char.isnumeric())): value
            for key, value in row.items()
            if key not in ["col_1", "sum"] and pd.notna(value)
        },
    }
    sum_dicts.append(sum_dict)

print(sum_dicts)
# Prints:
#
# [{4.0: 45.0, 5.0: 0.9, 7.0: 9.3}, {4.0: nan, 5.0: 4.5}, {49.2: 10.8, 3.0: 3.4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
out = []
for _, x in df.iterrows():
    out.append(
        {
            x["col_1"]: x["sum"],
            **{
                k: v
                for k, v in zip(
                    (3.0, 5.0, 7.0), x[["value_3", "value_5", "value_7"]]
                )
                if pd.notna(v)
            },
        }
    )

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{4.0: 45.0, 5.0: 0.9, 7.0: 9.3}, 
 {4.0: nan, 5.0: 4.5}, 
 {49.2: 10.8, 3.0: 3.4}]
```